# Can't create a new folder in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, user-folders

[image: Windows Explorer]
As shown in the picture above, I don't have the option of creating new folder anymore at anywhere of my PC, including all the disks.

I tried the following solutions I found on google, but they did not work in my case:

1. Restart the computer
2. Reset File Explorer (explorer.exe) process
3. Run System File Checker (SFC) scan
4. Perform [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
5. Edit the [Registry manually](https://windowsreport.com/fix-cannot-create-new-folder-windows-10/)
6. I turned off antivirus (Windows Defender, no 3rd party)
7. Clicking the Icon "New Folder" on the tool bar doesn't work
8. The shorcut of  Ctrl + Shift + N doesn't work either.

However, I can actually create folder through command prompt using `mkdir [NewFolderName]`.

**The things I didn't do:**

1. I haven't tried [repairing upgrade](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085) yet, it sounds like a radical solution that may work but I still would not know why the problem happened.Also I just reset the laptop, and this problem just randomly happened when I am trying to organize my disk. This issue occured after I tried to move my desktop folder to somewhere in disk E, instead of in disk C. I just reset it to the default location, but the issue persists.  I will try repair upgrade if nothing else works and will update here.
2. I didn't delete any windows update since I just reset my computer, the issue occured today. But here is a screenshot of recent updates
   [image: windows update]

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account).  Log out, Log into the new Windows Account.  Test your App and see if you can make a new file.

Comment: If you look in the registry at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew`, does it exist?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ShellNew doesn't exists! Do I need to create it?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Never mind, I found the answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed, and the solution is found [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-new-folder-entry-shellnew-windows-7/)

Basically, the cause of the issue is the default data for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder` in registry was changed to something like `ahk_folder`, and the correct value should be just `Folder`. I guessed this was due to my misclicking one executable in the autohotkey folder, which changed a value in my registry. But I forgot which specific executable did this.